# Inserting into a map of vectors

Tags: storage, frame

If I have a storage item defined as:

```
pub Foo get(fn foo): map hasher(twox_64_concat) u32 => Vec<T::AccountId>;
```

Do I always need to check if Foo contains the key before deciding to `insert` or `mutate`?

In other words, if I call insert when the key exists will it overwrite the value or append to it?

Answer (score 2):

You are using a map, so if your key exists and you call `insert` without checking if the key already exists, it will return the current value and overwrite it with the new value. If you use `mutate` it won't overwrite the key value unless you are doing so.

```rs
pub fn update_foo(foo_key: u32, new_account: T::AccountId) -> DispatchResult {
    // You can't do this, it will overwrite whatever you had
    // and set the value of the key to the new Account
    <Foo<T>>::insert(foo_key, new_account);
    Ok(())
}
```

I'll provide some examples, but keep in mind that I use FRAME v2 notation.

Using `insert`, if you want to append an `AccountId` to the value of your key, you should first retrieve the current vector as mutable, push your new `AccountId` and then `insert` the new vector on your key.

```rs
pub fn update_foo(foo_key: u32, new_account: T::AccountId) -> DispatchResult {
    let mut vector =
        <Foo<T>>::get(foo_key).ok_or(<Error<T>>::KeyNotFound)?;
    // Here im just pushing the value to the vector, but you can 
    // add any logic.
    vector.push(new_account);
    <Foo<T>>::insert(foo_key, vector);
    Ok(())
}
```

Using `mutate` is pretty much the same but you will push your new `AccountId` on a closure and in a single line perform the update.

```rs
pub fn update_foo(foo_key: u32, new_account: T::AccountId) -> DispatchResult {
    <Foo<T>>::mutate(foo_key, |vector| vector.push(new_account));
    Ok(())
}
```

Notice that using mutate I'm not controlling any possible error, but you can use `try_mutate` and handle errors.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks. In the case of mutate, if `foo_key` does not exist in the map, will it error?

Comment: No, when you call `get()` or `mutate()`, if there is no value present in the map, it will return the default instead, which for a vec is just an empty `vec![]`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to append to the Vec, the most efficient way is to take advantage of the [StorageAppend](https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/frame_support/storage/trait.StorageAppend.html) trait, and simply [append](https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/frame_support/storage/trait.StorageValue.html#tymethod.append) the item.

Using your map example, you could append to one of the `Vec`s like this:

```rust
fn append_account<T: Config>(map_id: u32, account_id: T::AccountId) {
    Foo::<T>::append(map_id, account_id)
}
```

Doing it this way avoids having to decode and encode the whole Vec just to push a new value.

Comment: I think this is the best option, I was running into some issues with the block production rate and it was because of the way I was inserting new values to a vector. Using append made the block production constant. thx!

Answer (score 0):

You can do the check or pattern matching in mutate closure.
For eg.

```
<Foo<T>>::mutate(key, |maybe| {
    if let Some(value) = maybe {
        value.push(input);
    } else {
        *maybe = vec![input];
    }
});
```

Another suggestion is to use BoundedVec instead of Vector when possible.